# How to move an imageview point to another imageview point in iOS?

Tags: ios, imageview

I want do a demo, this move  imageview1 to  imageview2, The rule of move is:   A  point in imageview1, B point in imageview2, I want to do  point A move to Point B, also imageview1 moved.

if  `imageview1` can be  handlePinchGesture   handlePanGesture   handleRotateGesture
what I do? imageview1.frame  howto get?

```
self.hairImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.hairImageView.transform, left_moved, hit_moved);
```

This `imageview1` continued up up up，not in correct point, `imageview1.frame` is also wrong.

Comment: you can use touch delegates for moving view within superview or simply use PanGesture to move from one location to another..look at http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/dragging-views-with-gestures   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4980534/dragging-uiview-under-finger

Comment: this is very good , but  this  <ImageView: 0x12a676b80; baseClass = UIImageView; frame = (55.2292 155.982; 190.614 222.796); transform = [0.51820300877044223, 0, 0, 0.51820300877044223, 0, 0]; opaque = NO; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x12a677e50>; layer = <CALayer: 0x12a676fe0>>         why  this  UIImageView not in correct point , this imageview  of data  is correct  ,how to change this view?

Comment: my idea is :  First calculate the position after move ,  Your idea is the opposite ,  so   how to move to right position is my care